# Need help reading file line by line

Tags: java, search, while-loop, filereader

The current code that I have reads only the last line of the file. Can someone help me establish a way so that the code reads a file line by line?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Searcher extends File {

    Scanner scn;

    public Searcher(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    public void search(String input)
    {

        try {
            scn = new Scanner(this);
            String data = "";

            while (scn.hasNext()) {
                data = scn.nextLine();
            }

            int count = 0, fromIndex = 0;
            while ((fromIndex = data.indexOf(input, fromIndex)) != -1) {
                count++;
                fromIndex++;
            }
            System.out.println("Total occurrences: " + count);

            scn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cant find file ");
        }
    }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Searcher search = new Searcher("src/ihaveadream.txt");
         search.search("we");
     }

}
```

appreciate any help !

Comment: You are **overwriting** value of your `data` string on each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (scn.hasNext()) {
    data = scn.nextLine();
}
```

You are replacing the value every time so you end up with the last value as that's what it gets set to in the end. Perhaps you wanted to append?

```
while (scn.hasNext()) {
    data = data + scn.nextLine();
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: This is "right" but concatenating strings like this has quadratic performance and in Java also has a really ugly (hidden) object creation per loop.  See Vadim's answer, esp. the last bit.

Comment: Agreed. I'd myself use a string builder instead. I suppose OP is writing a small scale program or just some testing code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's fair.  If the data is known to be small, then a simple loop like this may be all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem:

```
    while (scn.hasNext()) {
        data = scn.nextLine(); // right here
    }
```

each next line replaces previous line.

Depending on what you need you can either:
make all lines as one String

```
data = data + scn.nextLine();
 // another syntax to do the same:
data += scn.nextLine();
```

or use List to keep each line as separate element:

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
while (scn.hasNext()) {
        dataList.add(scn.nextLine());
    }
```

Comment: I like your last idea best, or maybe use a `StringBuilder` (*shock*).  Maybe even check the size of the file before reading and set the string builder to that size when you create it.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is definitely more proper, but IMHO check file size etc. is quite too much :-)

Comment: You have to load the file (and its directory entry) anyway, so it doesn't take any extra time.  And if you start with too small of a StringBuilder size, you end up with quadratic time.  Checking the file size first just means you set the StringBuilder to the right size to prevent any copying.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already suggested, you are replacing the the data in your data variable in the while loop, and since the loop runs till the end of the file is reached, only the last line is stored in the data variable, and any further processing on data would get you results only from the last line, so what you can do is what everybody else here suggested, or you can try this as an alternative solution (close the while loop after you check for index values):

```
public void search(String input)
{
    int count = 0, fromIndex = 0;  //moved outside so that we don't reset it to 0 with every iteration of the loop
    try {
        scn = new Scanner(this);
        String data = "";

        while (scn.hasNext()) {
            data = scn.nextLine();
        //} instead of here

        //int count = 0, fromIndex = 0; move these variables outside of the loop
        while ((fromIndex = data.indexOf(input, fromIndex)) != -1) {
            count++;
            fromIndex++;
        }
        } //close it here 
        System.out.println("Total occurrences: " + count);


        scn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cant find file ");
    }
}
```